# reload page on mobile browser javascript

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

I'm trying to reload my page every time the user puts my page in focus again or opens their browser. My code works, if the user is in the browser and changing pages, but it doesn't work if the user exit the browser (without actually shutting it completely down) and then opens the browser again, where my page would be the first site they see. I am testing this on chrome for android. Is there another event I need to listen for?

I am looking for a method to reload on all browsers as soon as the user enter my page, no matter what state it was in before - mobile browsers are especially important.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
onload = function () {
    onfocus = function () {
        onfocus = function () {}
        location.reload (true)
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty crazy idea to reload the page all the time in full, your users will hate you.  If you are going to do it, just do partial updates to the page.

Anyway, to answer the question, check the [PageVisibility API](https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/pagevisibility)(Chrome) or the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/).  This event fires when the page is visible to the user either by bringing the app into focus or by changing tabs.

Comment: For my site, I need to reload every time the user comes back, else they won't get the correct information. I only want to reload a part of the website, not the entire site, in this case my problem was just to even get it to reload. The user will come back in 30-40 minutes intervals, so it won't reload that often.